# How do I create a fileset in Apache Ant that includes child files but exclude the containing directory?

Tags: ant

I am able to create a fileset which includes certain directories. I am including this fileset to a copy. I want to take the child file and copy it without taking the parent folder.

My source structure is:

root

- Folder1

  - Folder2

    - script.js
  - Folder3

    - script2.js

So I want script.js and script2.js copied, but in the destination directory I get Folder2 and Folder3 included.

I'm out of depth. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [copy task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) with flatten attribute set to true :

> Ignore the directory structure of the source files, and copy all files
>   into the directory specified by the todir attribute. Note that you can
>   achieve the same effect by using a flatten mapper.